# Не понимаю в чем ошибка: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *


def save():
    txt=open('редактор.txt', 'w')
    txt.write(str(Text_vvod.get()))

window = Tk()
window.title("Редактор")
window.geometry("300x250")

main_menu = Menu()
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Save", command  = save)


window.config(menu=main_menu)

Text_vvod=Text(window,font='Arial 24', width=50, height=20).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Очевидно, в том, что вы в переменную `Text_vvod` помещаете результат вызова метода `pack()`, но этот метод ничего не возвращает и поэтому переменная `Text_vvod` пуста.

Comment: подскажешь как это исправить?

Comment: Вместо результата вывода метода `pack()` поместить в переменную то что вам нужно

Comment: Рабочих примеров работы с виджетом Text навалом в интернете https://younglinux.info/tkinter/text.php

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *


def save():
    txt=open('редактор.txt', 'w')
    txt.write(str(Text_vvod.get()))

window = Tk()
window.title("Редактор")
window.geometry("300x250")

main_menu = Menu()
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Save", command  = save)


window.config(menu=main_menu)

Text_vvod = Text(window,font='Arial 24', width=50, height=20)
Text_vvod.pack()
window.mainloop()
```